# Bluetooth discovery not working on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth

Even though I've checked the box for `Allow Bluetooth devices to find this computer` in Bluetooth settings, I still can't see my computer from other devices.

I'm sure that Bluetooth is working on my computer because it can find other devices, but it can't be found. How can I get it to be seen by other devices?

Comment: An HP document, but may be helpful..http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01590950&cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en

Comment: There can be number of reasons for that, for example: you have non-ascii utf chars in your pc name, some devices are just ignoring this. Please specify as much as you can - what BT adapter, drivers (default or not), etc.

Comment: The computer is probably only visible when actually requested, such as wehn you choose "recieve a file" or when you try to connect/pair a device. If you choose "recieve a file" then use another device to send a file see if it shows up then.